# What Java APIs should I look into for interacting with my microphone?

Tags: java, microphone, audio

I would like to build a recording software, for my own purposes, I would like it to be deployable on multiple systems (Windows and Unix) I am also building an application first time. So any help you would be able to provide on that topic as well it would be appreciated.

Please and thank you.

GC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any API for dealing with Microphones explicitly, but the Java Sound API should be able to see it as an input.  Specifically, the `javax.sound.sampled` classes.

Oracle has a (not-so-quick) [Java Sound Programmer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html) which includes Chapters on [Accessing Audio System Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter3.html) and [Capturing Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter5.html).

Comment: are there any online tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) if you only need to support OS/X and/or Windows.  I haven't used it or JavaSound recently enough to speak to which is better at the moment, but BASS was good enough to merit a looksee.